# How to fix reopen Drawer?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui

I have template: [SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-aryabhata-4uplkl?file=/src/App.tsx)

Why, when switching to a nested route, a double render occurs and thus the DRAWER is reopened. How to fix it? This effect u can watch inside "NEASTED" tab.

It is necessary that the first nested route opens by default.

Comment: It's unclear what specific issue you face. Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here in your question for the relevant code you are working and have the issue with? Can you also provide any debugging details? Is there an error? What are the *exact* steps to reproduce the issue? What is the expected versus the observed behavior?

Comment: There are no errors. Steps to reproduce - when you click on the button ( Open Drawer ), the driver opens and goes directly to the master ( General ) since this is a nested route and redirects to it from the main ('/'). So far so good. Then when I go to the next tab (Nested) there is another tab inside it, it's kind of double nested and at that moment (Drawer) reopens. How to get tired of it?

My expected behavior is that the Drawer is always static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have duplicate "drawer" routes. Remove the duplicate routes that are trying to redirect into the drawer, this allows the `"/drawer"` route to keep the `Drawer` component mounted. Use an index route in `"/drawer"` to redirect to `"/drawer/general"`.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Base />} />
        <Route path="drawer" element={<Drawer />}>
          <Route path="general" element={<General />} />
          <Route path="neasted" element={<NeastedTab />}>
            <Route path="general_2" element={<General_2 />} />
          </Route>
          <Route index element={<Navigate to="./general" />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-fix-reopen-drawer]